# How to find out what and where a program is writing to memory in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, memory, process

I want to make a tool which I can attach to another process and see where it writes to the memory, but I don't even know where to begin.

Any idea on how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will essentially have to write a debugger. Windows has [The Debugging Application Programming Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx) which you will need to use to accomplish this. This API is not simple and probably isn't designed to be called easily from VB.NET, so you probably have a challenging task ahead. But that's how you would begin.

Comment: Thanks that helps me start out at least.